# Craft Commerce Product Reveiws

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

For those who have implemented Craft Commerce and needed product reviews, what has been a good solution for you?

Comment: You might be able to use this plug-in and adapt it to `Commerce_Product` https://github.com/engram-design/Comments

Comment: Hello Bonfire has created a plugin for product reviews http://www.hellobonfire.com/product/product-reviews-plugin-for-craft

Comment: @RobErskine getting a craft error when going to that link mate.

Comment: @christopherhealey oy sorry. looks like they have taken that page down and I can't find it on github. I've cloned it from one of my legacy projects and hosted it on github: https://github.com/RobErskine/Product-Review

There seem to be a few other options for leaving product reviews these days too up on the official craft plugin store: https://plugins.craftcms.com/search?q=reviews